# customize validation messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

i want to know how to fully customize validation messages, this is how my code looks like

user_profile.rb:-

```
validates: first_name, :presence => {:message => "First name can't be blank"}
```

but this gives me an error message user profile first name First name can't be blank and what i want is to have an error message First name can't be blank. I look around for solution and i think i have to do some changes in en.yml file, but i don't know what to do. Any help?

Comment: can you show the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three options:

```
validate do |user|
  user.errors.add_to_base("First name can't be blank") if user.first_name.blank?
end
```

or

Doing user_profile.errors.full_messages will give you  -> `["First Name can't be blank"]`

```
validates: first_name, :presence => {:message => "can't be blank"}
```

or

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user_profile:
        first_name: "First name"
    errors:
      models:
        user_profile:
          attributes:
            first_name:
              blank: "can't be blank"
```

For more information on how to use locales, have a look at [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)

Comment: en.yml gives me an error i18n::invalidLocaleData...fount charachter that cant start any token while scanning for next token...and your 2nd option gives me "user profile first name can't be blank" but what i want is only "First name can't be blank"

Comment: for the 2nd option, How are you accessing the errors? user_profile.errors.full_messages should give you what you want

Comment: for the 3rd option, i think your yaml format is wrong. You can check your YAML validity using YAMLLint -> http://yamllint.com/

Comment: got it working with 3rd one..can you please explain it a bit. I'm pretty naive about how to use en.yml file :)

Comment: Option 3 did exactly what I wanted.  Thanks for the link to how to use locales.  That was helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses their own error handling. Which means that it shows the database column. This results into *name of column* *can't be blank.

Try using something like this and only thing you have to do is change your model.

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2>
   <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>
   probited this <%= object.class.to_s.underscore.humanize.downcase %> from being saved
  </h2>
  <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
  <ul>
  <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
   <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>


<% end %>
```

Besides that, I'd use Javascript/HTML5 validation for blank fields. To decrease bandwith usage.
Hope this helps.

Comment: you didnt get my question.. i know how to show error messages..what i want to do is to customize them