# Rails prints "Can't be blank" instead my custom error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In User model I wrote:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password

    validates :name, :presence => { allow_blank: false, message: "This field can't be empty" }
end
```

But it prints "Can't be blank". What is the problem here?

**UPDATE**

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        redirect_to "http://bookworm.az:3000"
    else
        session[:name] = @user.name
        session[:username] = @user.username
        session[:email] = @user.email

        error = @user.errors.to_a.to_sentence(two_words_connector: ',')
        delimeter = error.split
        error = error.gsub(delimeter[0], '')

        show_error = error.split(",")

        flash[:notice] = show_error[0]
        redirect_to :back
    end
```

View code:

```
   <% if flash[:notice] %>
        <p class="error">
            <%= flash[:notice] %>
        </p>
    <% end %>
```

Yesterday it works! But today - no! I did not change anything!

Comment: well the code seems fine, could you print the error line

Comment: You can find the different options to do this here:


http://stackoverflow.com/a/19320190/3185510

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady just `can't be blank`

Comment: That's weird, it's [documented that way](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates)...

Comment: does it work when you remove `allow_blank` ?

Comment: display the contents in view also..

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady no, the same result

Comment: What's your ruby and rails version?

Comment: @RajeshCO the other error messages displays correctly! Just in blank it types "Can't be blank"

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Rails 4.1, ruby 2

Comment: why you can not use `@user.save!` instead of `@user.save`

Answer (score 3):

Use locales to show customized error messages since it is the most recommended way:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        name: ""
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "This field can't be empty"
```

Hey, you could see `config/locales/en.yml` file by default in a Rails application. So, make use of it since you want to customize the error message and it is the suggested way. If it was a direct one, it would have been easy to do it in a `Model` itself.

**Model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
    validates_presence_of :name
end
```

**Controller:**

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
        redirect_to "http://bookworm.az:3000"
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```

**View:**

```
<%= @user.errors.full_messages.first if @user.errors.any? %>
```

Please try as above. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Did you restart the server after making sure you have updated exactly similar to my answer? If yes, Now you should show me your form and the way you have shown the error_messages in view.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
# config/locales/en.yml

 en:
   activerecord:
     attributes:
       name: "Name"

   errors:
     models:
      user:
        attributes:
          name:
            blank: "This field can't be empty"
```

In controller

```
 def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save!
     redirect_to "http://bookworm.az:3000"
  else


    render :new
  end
end
```

In View

```
 <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
   <ul>
     <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
   </ul>
   ....
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I did this variant, too. Nothing. The same result

Comment: So, it will be "Name This field can't be empty", right? Is that the one needed?

Comment: yes, but I need it in model, not in locales @RajeshCO